# Python while/if loop ignoring condition

Tags: python, while-loop, pyautogui

I'm writing a basic `while/if` loop to scroll down the page when `nextbutton.png` is not on the screen, and stop scrolling when the button is on the screen.

It should print `True` if the button isn't on the screen and print the button's location if it is. 
Problem is, when I run this code, I get the following output:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

The way this code is written, it should never output `False`, either `True` or the location. I can provide the website I'm attempting this on with instructions on how to replicate the output, but I suspect that I've made a simple logical mistake in constructing the loop.

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('nextbutton.png', confidence=0.9) is None:
        print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('nextbutton.png', confidence=0.9) is None)
        time.sleep(random.randint(0,3000)/1000) 
        pyautogui.press('pagedown')
    else:
        x4, y4 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('nextbutton.png', confidence=0.9)
        print(x4,y4)
        break
```

Comment: It can print `False`... if the result of `pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...)` has changed between the two successive calls. For example, what if you simulate the PageDown keypress, but it takes the application a little while to render the button? It might help to put the `time.sleep` call _after_ the `pyautogui.press` call, but this sort of code is inherently brittle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the function `locateOnScreen()` 2 times, and it might return different outputs each time.

I suggest using a variable to hold the output of `locateOnScreen()` to avoid that race condition. Maybe this can work for you:

```
import pyautogui

while True:
    v = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('nextbutton.png', confidence=0.9)
    if v is None:
        print(v is None)
    ...
```